# Get max number out of strings

Tags: python

I have the following 'numbers', which are actually strings from a regex:

```
nums = ['1', '4', '9', '10']
```

I would like to get the max, which would be `10`. Is there a cleaner way to do this than to do a list comprehension, such as:

```
>>> max(nums)
'9'
>>> max([int(item) for item in nums])
10
```

Otherwise, it would give me `9`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`max` has a keyword argument `key` that takes a callable which transforms the values in some way before comparing them.

```
>>> max(nums, key=int)
```

This is essentially the same as your list comprehension `max(int(item) for item in nums)`, except that it's important to note that the *original values* are returned, not the *transformed values*. This means that:

```
>>> a = max(nums, key=int)
>>> b = max(int(item) for item in nums)
>>> repr(a), repr(b)
('10', 10)
```

Comment: Does this just call `map` under the hood? I cant test atm but wondering how this performs compared to OP's approach

Comment: `max(nums, key=int)` is not the same as `max(int(item) for item in nums)`, as the former returns a string, while the latter returns an integer.

Comment: That's easily fixed with `int(max(nums, key=int))` though.

Comment: I would generally not use `key` just to retype data; the behavior is not intuitive and it ends up turning into code that often doesn't do what you think it does. It's always better to explicitly retype. IMO.

Comment: @CJ59 I can't agree with you, sorry.

Comment: @roganjosh it does not just call `map` under the hood, but I can't tell you what the performance comparison is. [here's the dis](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/396786e5be563748fbc73b8d8d951ff7)

Comment: I'll test when I get back :)

Comment: @AdamSmith I say this because I've run into code like this before: `if max(vals, key=int) != 0:`. It's not obvious why this is not a good way to cast data that's not type-safe for a comparison (and not easy to find later on).

Comment: @CJ59 "It's not obvious why this is not a good way to cast data" No data gets cast -- I'm not sure why it would be?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `map` function:

```
>>> max(map(int, nums))
```