# Getting highest value from a dict of numbers as strings

Tags: python, dictionary, max

```
production = {
        'item1': '500',
        'item2': '10000',
    }
```

I'm trying to get the highest value from that dict, which would be 10000. However, I'm getting 500 as return of `max(production.values())`.

I believe it's like that because it's getting the highest value from string, not int (taking the lexicographical order of their codepoints).

Could someone help me with a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Not the best duplicate target. The duplicates list could be updated, for example, with this question: [Get max number out of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53196684/7851470)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) takes a key property which you can use to convert data for the calculation:

```
production = {
    'item1': '500',
    'item2': '10000',
}

# base max calculation on integer version of value
max(production.values(), key=int) # assuming all are integers
# '10000'
```

This will leave the values as you have them in the dictionary — so the returned value will remain a string.

It's also handy if you want the key as well:

```
max(production.items(), key=lambda pair: int(pair[1]))
# ('item2', '10000')
```

Answer (score 5):

Not the answer you should accept, but providing some background on performance:

```
from random import randint
from timeit import timeit

# generating 1,000 dictionaries of random keys with random string values
dicts = [{k: str(randint(1, 10000)) for k in range(10000)} for _ in range(1000)]


def all_max1():
    # the answer provided by @MarkMeyer
    return [max(d.values(), key=int) for d in dicts]


def all_max2():
    # the answer provided by @Marceline
    return [max(int(x) for x in d.values()) for d in dicts]


print(timeit(all_max1, number=10))
print(timeit(all_max2, number=10))
```

The answer @MarkMeyer provided is almost twice as fast as the answer provided by @Marceline, though both are technically correct.

Result:

```
7.4847795
11.341150599999999
```

The advice of @JHeron is good advice in that if you can avoid having strings in that position in the first place, using integers would be more efficient - but I assume your data comes in the form of strings.

However, if you need to operate on those values more than once (for more than just a single max value), you may consider first converting the original data and avoid multiple conversions later.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert them to integers and take max value out of them

```
max(int(x) for x in production.values())
```

Comment: The answer is correct, but doesn't need the square brackets (turning it into a list to pass to `max`), as `max` can also take it from a generator - just leave `[]` off.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this output because the values are Strings.
To achieve a correct max() comparison, the values must be numbers.

```
production = {
        'item1': 500,
        'item2': 10000,
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the values are inserted into the keys using OCR. I don't think there's a way to structure the dict directly using int values.